# Explain better how CompuBERT handles math tokens on input

Tags: information-retrieval

My question is about [CompuBERT](https://github.com/MIR-MU/CompuBERT) ([Three is Better than One Ensembling Math Information Retrieval Systems](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2696/paper_235.pdf))

It is written on page 21 (table 2):

> "we assigned a distinct mask for math tokens on input, often used to
> distinguish between different input languages"

I haven't found the implementation of the assignement of a distinct mask for math tokens on input but I will ask anyway two closely related questions:

1. How does CompuBERT recognize expressions like c_{0} and c_0 are the same as $c_0$?
2. Different calligraphic fonts should be assigned the same mask sometimes, for example like the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ or simply $R$ if someone lazy type as input R instead \mathbb{R}... If this problem is not solved I think CompuBERT will not understand what the intention of the input question... How this problem is solved?

(please tell me where the implementation of the mask is in the code)

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors?

Comment: Yes, by e-mail. but for other few questions few days ago. One author answered some questions and the other author never answered any question.